# How can I bind a command to the F1 key?

Tags: key-bindings

If I change:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c d") 'org-toggle-todo-and-fold)
```

to eg:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "F1") 'org-toggle-todo-and-fold)
```

This doesn't work.

Is there a way to map to F keys such as the F1 key?

Answer (score 5):

I think any key name that's more than one character needs to be be inside `<>`, so try

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f1>") 'org-toggle-todo-and-fold)
```

Comment: It certainly does not work. Executing `emacs -Q`, enabling `text-mode`, then evaluating a `(define-key text-mode-map (kbd "<F1>") 'foo)` and pressing `F1` results in Emacs asking me if I want to press something else to complete the keybinding *(whereas I'd expect it to print error about `foo` being undefined)*. As a matter of fact, the following also do nothing to this default keybinding: `(global-set-key (kbd "<F1>") nil)`, `(define-key nil (kbd "<F1>") nil)`, `(bind-key "<F1>" nil)`, `(local-unset-key (kbd "<F1>"))`. How to make it work is still a question.

Comment: You're right. I had an error. It needs to be `<f1>` not `<F1>`. I tested with `(define-key global-map (kbd "<f1>") 'foo)` and it tried running foo instead of being a prefix key waiting for me to press something else.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Your answer is correct in that F keys need to be enclosed in <> brackets. This is very helpful.

I had assumed though that F1 was available in emacs but it is already bound.

I then found that F5 to F9 are available to the user.

This is outlined at
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html

I also found that a lower case f must be used eg  `"<f5>"`

Since `kbd "<F1>"` would not fully work because:

1. F1 is bound
2. It needs to be lower case

I thought I would add an answer that is more complete because if I left a comment to your answer, it may not be obvious to people to see.

So:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f5>") 'org-toggle-todo-and-fold)
```

does work fully.

I don't mean to "steal" someone's answer though :)